# How to prepare an Executor service for Apache Camel route's Split, org.apache.camel.spi.ThreadPoolProfile vs java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-spring-dsl

In the multithreading guide of Apache Camel there is an example on ThreadPoolProfile usage as a parameter for executorServiceRef (https://camel.apache.org/manual/threading-model.html):

```
<threadPoolProfile xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="fooProfile"
                       poolSize="20" maxPoolSize="50" maxQueueSize="-1"/>
<route>
       <multicast strategyRef="myStrategy" executorServiceRef="fooProfile">
          ...
       </multicast>
    </route>
```

I was expecting the same approach for the routes using split, as it has executorServiceRef attribute too.

So, I prepare ang register the bean in the registry:

```
    ThreadPoolProfileBuilder builder = new ThreadPoolProfileBuilder("only5threads");
    ThreadPoolProfile only5threads = builder.poolSize(5).maxPoolSize(5).maxQueueSize(-1).build();
    final org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry customRegistry = new org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry();
    customRegistry.put("only5threads", only5threads);
```

then I refer the executor service the same way in my split:

```
    <split parallelProcessing="true" executorServiceRef="only5threads">
      ....
```

But surprisingly, it expects another Object type:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.camel.spi.ThreadPoolProfile to java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3611)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(SimpleRegistry.java:47)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

So, what I should pass as an executor service and how to produce it from ThreadPoolProfile if it is not accepted here. There are no any examples of custom Thread Pool Profile for `split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have to refer the ExecutorService and create an object of it and put it to the registry:

```
  ThreadPoolProfileBuilder builder = new ThreadPoolProfileBuilder("only5threads");
        ThreadPoolProfile threadPoolProfile = builder.poolSize(5).maxPoolSize(5).maxQueueSize(-1).build();
        DefaultExecutorServiceManager defaultExecutorServiceManager = new DefaultExecutorServiceManager(camelContext);
        defaultExecutorServiceManager.setDefaultThreadPoolProfile(threadPoolProfile);
        ExecutorService executorService = defaultExecutorServiceManager.newDefaultScheduledThreadPool("only5threads","only5threads");
```

adding it to registry

```
 final org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry customRegistry = new 
org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry(); customRegistry.put("only5threads", only5threads);
```

calling them in route's XML

```
<split parallelProcessing="true" executorServiceRef="only5threads">
```